# What happens if database connection is closed or database server is down immediately executing a query

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

Assuming this simple query.

```
var knex = require("knex")(knexConfig);
    var insert1 = {col1: "a4", col2: "b4", col3: "c4"};

    knex.insert(insert1).into("test").then(function (id) {
      console.log(id);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      knex.destroy();
    });
```

what happens if database server is down or connection closed immediately after executing insert query? Does it stores data and return error or it does not store data and return error?

Comment: It may insert or it may not.  It may send an error or it may not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In that case, how backend should handle such cases?

Comment: @UserBH Unclear what that means. If the backend is the database, it has initiated the case, it doesn't have to 'handle' it. If it is the application, it can't handle it if it doesn't receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

If the insert query has been executed, but results has not been sent to client yet, data will be stored in DB but `knex` will throw an error, that connection was lost.

If that would have been done in transaction, in that case data would not have been stored and `knex` would have thrown same kind of error.

In this case you should probably do the insert in transaction so that you will know that if there has been some error, data is not inside DB... however there is still possibility that after adding row to DB for example express fails returning result to REST call and your frontend again cannot be sure if data was inserted or not, since there was an error.

So best way to handle this kind of case is to just trust that data is there if everything was successful and that if there was an error, user should check if the data was added or not (in real life if this is not critical just assume that data was not added and try again, if it is critical that the same data is not posted twice, make sure that database schema has some constraints preventing it).

Comment: In real life you should make the transaction idempotent. No check required.

Comment: @EJP last part of my answer actually did say that too, but with more words